# max(date) sql query in laravel 5.2

Tags: sql, laravel-5, eloquent, max

I just wonder how to use below MySQL query in laravel5.2 using eloquent.

```
SELECT MAX(date) AS "Last seen date" FROM instances WHERE ad_id =1
```

I have column date in instance table .

I would like to select the latest date from that table where ad_id =1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to get the `date` column only then use the following:

```
$instance = Instance::select('date')->where('ad_id', 1)->orderBy('date', 'desc')->first();
```

Or if you want to get all the instances related to that latest date then use:

```
$instance = Instance::where('ad_id', 1)->orderBy('date', 'desc')->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

To actually select the max though you can now:

```
Instance::latest()->get();
```

Documentation: [laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries)

Comment: Correct if the date field you're wanting to order by is the `created_at` column. This might not always be the case, though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$instance = Instance::where('ad_id', 1)->orderBy('date', 'desc')->first();
```